# How to initialize properties with inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, properties, console-application

Hello I am trying to initialize a property called Amount while trying to incorporate inherited classes. When I have constructor for the property all my derived classes throw errors. When I remove the constructor that is in the application all the errors are gone. Is this the right thing to do? Do I need the constructor for my property? My code is below, any advice is appreciated.

```
class Account
{
    public long Amount { get; set; }

    public Account(long amount)
    {
        Amount = amount;
    }
}

class Banking : Account
{
}

class Savings : Account
{
}
```

Comment: Please re-read [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question to include exact error messages (and ideally remove code unrelated to the error itself). While editing, add results of your research on particular error code you are getting (should look like CSxxxx) and explain why Microsoft documentation and existing SO posts on the same error did not give you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Default constructors (the one with no parameters) are implicit when you don’t have any other constructors. So your base class is missing the default  constructor. Alternatively all your derived classes should call a base constructor from their constructor. If you don’t call this it is also implicit. You should add constructors on the derived classes and call base(value)?

```
class Account
{
    public long Amount { get; set; }

    public Account(long amount)
    {
        Amount = amount;
    }
}

class Banking : Account
{
    public Backing() : base(0)
    {
         // This constructor enables you to initialize the amount with zero
    }
}

class Savings : Account
{
    public Savings(long amount) : base(amount)
    {
        // This constructor enables you to initialize the amount
    }
}
```